# MySQL not logging queries to general_log table

Tags: mysql

I've tried getting the general_log table working in MySQL 5.7.29, I've run the following code and it executes fine, but there are no rows in the general_log table after executing more select statements - eg it looks like it's not actually logging anything. Any help is much appreciated!

```
use mysql;
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';

DROP TABLE general_log;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,  -- Be careful with this one.
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
);

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';

select * from mysql.general_log
order by event_time desc;
```

To be clear I've run the documentation once, including setting the general_log to `ON` and log_output to `TABLE`, but when running other queries nothing is added to the log.

Comment: The code you display deletes/drops and then rebuilds the General Log table each time the code is run. Is this intended?

Comment: You have not shown any code for writing to the general log table

Comment: have you [followed the instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)?

Comment: Sorry to be clear I've run this once, including setting the general_log to ON and log_output to TABLE, but when running other queries nothing is added to the log.

Comment: @patricknz I ran into the same problem. Could you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the general log. 
**After, you should run a query on a different table.**

Please run the following commands:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
--With the log disabled, rename the log file externally (for example, from the command line). Then enable the log again:

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

select * from another_table;

select * from mysql.general_log
order by event_time desc;
```

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html for full instructions